# Why should I use "as keyof typeof lookup" in an object lookup?

Tags: typescript

I have recently stepped into a piece of code similar to this

```
const lookup = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };
const res = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map((value) => lookup[value as keyof typeof lookup]);
```

I do not understand which is the point of coding this `lookup[value as keyof typeof lookup]` vs a simpler `lookup[value]`.

What do I gain adding `as keyof typeof lookup`?

Comment: `value` argument resolves to string whereas `lookup` objects allows you to use only allowed keys to index. Because type `string` is much wider than `a, b, c, d` TS gives you an error. In order to fix that error author uses type assertions to assure typescript that this expression is valid

Comment: You can use `as const ` assertion and get rid of `as keyof` assertion. See example: `const res = (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as const).map((value) => lookup[value])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cast is necessary because the type of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` is being inferred as `string[]` which is too wide to be used as the keys of `lookup`.

Another way of fixing this would be with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like this:

```
const lookup = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 };

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as const;

const res = keys.map((value) => lookup[value]);
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiEBrArgBxgXhgbxgQwC4YBGAGhgCNiAmC4YgZgoBNiAWGAXwG4AoPqEiwkAUwCeELDADaAcnxyKcykphzgauSzkBdAlKHR+g8NBgAnUVOxjJAOgC2+NAApXAN3xwUogJRYAHzwiKhoMl4+orp+-EA)

This solution is slightly better because the type is being inferred from the actual value. In your example you arbitrarily tell TypeScript that `value` is of type `keyof typeof lookup` while it may not be so it's less safe.

Comment: Thanks. It seems though that in order to have the compiler raise the error, you need to specify either `"strict": true` or `"noImplicitAny": true` in the `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json